# In Gatling, how can I generate a random number each time a call is executed? (not using feeder)

Tags: performance-testing, gatling

I need to find a way to generate a random number each time the REST call is executed.

I have the following GET call:

```
    exec(http("Random execution")
      .get("/randomApi")
      .queryParam("id", getRandomId()))
  }
```

Obviously it doesn't work as the random number is only generated once and I end up with the same 
number whenever this call is executed. I cant use the feeder option as my feeder is already huge and is generated by a 3rd party for each test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.queryParam takes Expressions as its arguments, and since Expression is an alias for a session function, you can just do...

```
.queryParam("id", session => getRandomId())
```

You could also define a second feeder that uses a function to generate the values - no need to update your existing feeder or add another csv file. This would be useful if you had more complicated logic for getting / generating an Id

```
val idFeeder = Iterator.continually(Map("id" -> Random.nextInt(999999)))

//in your scenario...
.feed(idFeeder)
.exec(http("Random execution")
  .get("/randomApi")
  .queryParam("id", "${id}")
)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of having options, another option you have is to store an object in the session that support toString, which generates whatever you need.  It's a nifty trick that you can use for all kinds of things.

```
object RANDOM_ID {
  toString() { return RandomId().toString() }
}
... 
exec( _.set( "RANDOM_ID", RANDOM_ID ) )
...
.exec( 
  http("Random execution")
  .get("/randomApi")
  .queryParam( "id", "${RANDOM_ID}" )
)
```

You can apply the same principle to generating random names, addresses, telephone numbers, you name it.

So, which is the better solution?  The feeder, or the object in session?

Most of the time, it'll be the feeder, because you control when it is updated.  The object in session will be different every time, whereas the feeder solution, you control when the value updates, and then you can reference it multiple times before you change it.

But there may be instances where the stored object solution results in easier to read code, provided you are good with the value changing every time it is accessed.  So it's good to know that it is an option.